# Moving Linux image to a different hardware

Tags: hardware, cloning

Should I expect any issues with physically moving Ubuntu 22.04 image on SSD to another, similar PC? The only differences are CPUs (from i5-9600K to i5-12600) and motherboards.

Comment: you should always expect issues, that way there are no surprises because you prepare for failure before you start (doing backups, etc)

Comment: @jsotola Backup is a given. I meant software issues strictly related to SSD move from one box to another.

Comment: Absolutely none.

Comment: Is video the same? Only if proprietary driver's installed like nVidia and different version then required.  I suggest new install & restore data & apps from backup. It becomes a good test that your backup works as you never know if backup is correct until you try to restore it.

Comment: @oldfred Video is provided by integrated Intel GPU in both cases. The same driver should work well.